# Javascript or jQuery fill data based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to get a solution in order to simplify the login for my staff. Ideally I am looking for a js or jQuery script that pre-fills 2 input fields based upon the data they enter.

E.g. the main field should be: Enter token

IF the token equals 123 then fill input1 and input2 with certain amount of data, while if the token is 456 fill it with other data - if no token matches then do not fill any data. I know this is very unsecure but since it's something running only locally it would work for my specific needs.

```
<style>.hidden {display: none !important;}</style>

<form>
    <input id="token" type="text">
    <input class="hidden" id="input1" type="text">
    <input class="hidden" id="input2" type="password">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Some advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything that isn't working as expected? You're basically wanting to add an `input` event listener to `#token` and set the values of the hidden inputs based on the value entered. Is that close to what you have or are you going down a different track?

Comment: Please provide the script you have tried, only then we can help you

Comment: FYI, you can use `<input type="hidden">` instead of hiding them with CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically wanting to [add an `input` event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to [`#token`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [set the values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) of the hidden inputs based on the [value entered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Something like this should suffice...

```js
// make sure this script goes AFTER the HTML

// A map of token to values
const secrets = {
  123: {
    input1: 'input1 123',
    input2: 'input2 123'
  },
  456: {
    input1: 'input1 456',
    input2: 'input2 456'
  }
}

const input1 = document.getElementById('input1')
const input2 = document.getElementById('input2')

document.getElementById('token').addEventListener('input', e => {
  const token = e.target.value
  
  // get the values or if the token doesn't exist, sensible defaults
  const secret = secrets[token] || {
    input1: '',
    input2: ''
  }
  input1.value = secret.input1
  input2.value = secret.input2
}, false)
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="token" type="text" placeholder="Enter token">
  <input class="hidden" id="input1" type="text">
  <input class="hidden" id="input2" type="password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Its pretty simple, You can get the desired result by using the conditional statement like if else.

here is the solution for your problem.

```
var token=$('#token').val();
if(token==123)
{
  $('#input1').val('value1'); //set the value which you want to place here
  $('#input2').val('value2'); //set the value which you want to place here
}
else if(token==456)
{
  $('#input1').val('value1'); //set the value which you want to place here
  $('#input2').val('value2'); //set the value which you want to place here
}
else {
  $('#input1').val('');
  $('#input1').val('');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the jquery code given below:

```
<script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#token').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 123) {
        $('#input1').val('1'); //assign the value you want
        $('#input2').val('1'); //assign the value you want
    } else if($(this).val() == 456) {
        $('#input1').val('2'); //assign the value you want
        $('#input2').val('2'); //assign the value you want
    } else {
        $('#input1').val('');
        $('#input2').val('');
    }
  });
</script>
```